# Gray area w ImageMagick "-distort Perspective" despite transparent virtual pixels

Tags: imagemagick

I took this image:

[image]

and did this:

```
convert -extent 800x600 -background transparent -matte -virtual-pixel transparent -distort Perspective '0,0,369,225 0,255,357,195 255,0,400,218 255,255,400,187' image1.png image2.png
```

The result (intentionally using display's checkered mode to show transparency):

[image]

How do I make the nasty grey area go transparent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add "-mattecolor transparent":

```
convert -extent 800x600 -mattecolor transparent -background transparent -matte -virtual-pixel transparent -distort Perspective '0,0,369,225 0,255,357,195 255,0,400,218 255,255,400,187' test.png test2.png
```

Your example image with yout example parameters, using mattercolor:

[image: Example image with correct transparency]

Documentation of mattecolor option when using perspective explains (http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php):

> The horizon is anti-aliased, and the 'sky' color may be set using the -mattecolor setting.

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted, thanks! I'd poked around the docs for hours, but hadn't found the -mattecolor thing.